# What's the benefit for making batch call when design API?

Tags: rest

Confused about making batch call when building Restful API. 
For example, I want to check 100 students height. What's the difference among: 
1) check height one by one
2) check height with a batch of 20
3) check height with a batch of 50

What's the benefit of it? I know batching will decrease HTTP requests amount. Will this count much when we evaluate the speed of an API?

How to choose the batch size?

Comment: Yes, batching reduces network overhead and depending on how long each API call takes this can be significant.

Comment: Batching comes into play when there are lots of records involved. It doesn't make much difference in case of 20 or 50 records. Lets say you want to process 10K or 1 million records, this is when you would want to batch and process each batch separately. It is not just about network overhead but the entire processing cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have found this with a bit of googling - but I'll answer here all the same.

The benefits of batching generally depends on what you do with it.

If you have a keep-alive connection, you have no overhead of handshaking, and then you don't spend too much time dealing with subsequent packets along this connection. You can then pipeline requests and decrease your latency.  However, in HTTP1.1, requests are still FIFO - so you have to 'handshake' each and every one.  This is where you can leverage the power of batching!

Because you can send/retrieve all the data you need for all requests hereafter, you can minimize the overheads incurred from setting up each individual HTTP connection. This *does* mean that you will have to wait a bit longer to handle the request as everything is packed into one request, but your throughput improves.  The reason for this is the roundtrip from making first request to receiving final response is not multiplied by the number of requests you have to make.

Something to keep in mind, however, is TTFB - time to first byte. If you load data progressively, it can be perceived as faster by a user. Imagine a website which loads one of each one thousand resources at a time, and you as a user can see these popping up, versus a website that loads all one thousand at once, and you just see a spinner until all the resources have been loaded? I'll bet you find the progressive loading scheme "looks" faster.

Naturally, batching very much depends on what you're doing with the requests, if it is to be worthwhile.

Sometimes, you have to be careful with batching, as you can put a lot of load on a server if you have multiple users concurrently making batch requests, and it might be a better balancing scheme to process requests sequentially.  Of course, you will be able to figure this out with a bit of monitoring and analytics.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Questions about load issues you mentioned about batching, suppose we have n users make batch calls(batch size is m), will the load to server in this circumstance equal to the situation when m*n users make single calls to server?

Comment: It really all depends on the nature of the request and the type of infrastructure you have. I think you'd have a hard time equating the two, however, because a few requests processing very large sets of data is inherently different in nature to many requests processing small sets of data.